# Collect list function in hive and impala

Tags: hive, impala

I am using

```
concat_ws(' ',  collect_list(field1)) as field1,
```

but the query is not running in impala. 
Does impala not support this function? 
If not, what is an alternative for a similar operation in impala?

Answer (score 3):

You can use group_concat() function in impala,
Plase refer https://www.cloudera.com/documentation/enterprise/5-5-x/topics/impala_group_concat.html